# Putting all request data in a URI vs in an object (REST)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Is one way better than the other? What are any unique advantages/disadvantages to each approach, if there are any? 
 Both ways are valid implementations of a RESTful API if their request contains all the necessary data, right?

For example, doing

```
app.get('/:field1/:field2/:field3' , (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.params.field1);
  console.log(req.params.field2);
  console.log(req.params.field3);

  res.send("success");
})
```

versus

```
app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
   console.log(req.body.field1);
   console.log(req.body.field2);
   console.log(req.body.field3);

   res.send("success");
}
```

Sorry if this is so wrong that it's cringeworthy, I'm still kind of confused with REST.

Comment: If you making fetch data from somewhere like database or API call, you should use the `get` method else you can use the `post` to store data.

Comment: While using GET, keep in mind your parameters would be appened to URL. So in case your parameter length increases the specified limit, your GET call would not go through successfully.

Comment: @atinjanki What would you do if the parameter length does exceed the limit?

Comment: @Stoodent  I'd use POST in such case

Comment: @atinjanki doesn't that go against what Prathamesh said about using the get method to fetch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second request suggests a `POST` request. There's many ways to skin this cat, on a high level people like to do the following:

- Use the URL to identify what you are operating on.
- Use methods like `GET` to retrieve data from the server.
- Use methods `POST`, `PUT` to make changes.

I would highly suggest you look into API documentation from some existing APIs and get some inspiration. Information can be sent in many ways, but where that information appears (query parameter, body, other parts of the url) tends to have a fairly specific meaning.

I also found this resource a good one for a good 'default set of rules' to follow when designing APIs:

https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md

Answer (score 1):

If you making fetch data from somewhere like database or API call, you should use the `get` method else you can use the `post` to store data.

Check out more details:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/